# Save New Data Form - Form resets and will not redirect to the custom list page or used ?Source

Tags: sharepoint-server, custom-list

I am using SharePoint 2013 OP with SPD 2013.

I created a Custom List. When I select save or cancel on the New Item form, the form resets and does not move forward or backwards (depending on what was pressed).

Any idea as to why this is happening? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1.Make sure that you have filled out all the fields which are required fields.

2.Which the browser are you using? Please go to another browser then have a test.

3.Try to create a new custom list, add new item, compare the result.

4.Any error messages?